# SharePoint Client Object Model - UndoCheckOut did not work

Tags: development, csom

I am trying to Discard Check Out on a specific Checked Out SharePoint file but I got stuck.

Here is my code snippet:

```
//Define a ClientContext with the specific Share Point site Url.
var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
var folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl);

//Get specific folder`s Url, where the target file exists.
ctx.Load(folder, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

//Get file`s data.
var targetFileName = "someFile.txt";
var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(folder.ServerRelativeUrl + targetFileName);
ctx.Load(file, f => f.Exists, f => f.Name);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

//Output file data to ensure that we got exactly that file. That WriteLine provides required output without any errors.
Console.WriteLine($"File Data\n--> Exists: {file.Exists}\n--> Name: {file.Name}");


//Try to Undo Check Out. DID NOT WORK ??? File is checked out 100500%!
file.UndoCheckOut();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

The problem is that when I’m trying to execute the UndoCheckOut method - it throws the following kind of exception:

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: The file "cst/PTFixLists/RPA_Robot testing folder/Combined Fix list and Manual Errors 5-14-18 2.xlsx" is not checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line of code

```
var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(folder.ServerRelativeUrl + targetFileName);
```

with

```
var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(folder.ServerRelativeUrl +"/"+ targetFileName);
```

Comment: I did, but it still not working.

Comment: Go to Library settings->Versioning Settings, then check if "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" set to "No".

Comment: This setting is set to "No".

Comment: Create a new library to check if it works.